# Deploying Universal Angular on Google Cloud Function or AWS Lambda

Tags: angular, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework

While experimenting with Angular 2, I happened to [see Angular Universal.](https://universal.angular.io/quickstart/) It's Server-side Rendering for Angular 2 apps same like we have in ReactJs. There is also a getting started guide with one code snippet [here](https://universal.angular.io/quickstart/).

I am trying to understand if this is something we can deploy in serverless environment like Google Cloud Function or AWS Lambda. Docs of both services indicates that nodejs is supported. I am very new to both Angular2 & serverless hosting pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to deploy Angular app on serverless environment. I could say more, it is possible with server-side rendering (Angular Universal).

Check out this boiler-plate repo:
https://github.com/maciejtreder/angular-universal-pwa

and live demo:
https://www.angular-universal-pwa.maciejtreder.com

The app is deployed using Serverless framework: https://serverless.com

Answer (score 3):

Don't think so. It says you need to use angular2+webpack and that starter guide says it requires node version => 5. AWS lambda supports only 4.3.2.

Don't know about google functions.

Comment: now it is posible AWS Lambda Supports Node.js v6.10 https://medium.com/@Lawrence_IO/server-less-side-rendering-with-angular-cd50fa8ff176