# Angular 4 Universal on AWS Lambda

Tags: angular, aws-lambda, angular-universal

There is a way to implement Universal to run on Lambda?,  I want to deploy my APP using Cloudfront without needing a server and Lambda looks nice to it. Did anyone made a try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying Universal Angular on Google Cloud Function or AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282468/deploying-universal-angular-on-google-cloud-function-or-aws-lambda)

Answer (score 4):

Hello You can check out my boiler plate for that:

https://github.com/maciejtreder/angular-universal-serverless

Or, you can make a use of the [ng-toolkit](https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit):

```
ng add @ng-toolkit/serverless
```

Like in this article:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/angular-universal-javascript-node-js-aws-lambda

Comment: is there any docs on how to configure cloudfront to access the deployment?